# How to find and replace string without use command Sed?

Tags: shell, text-processing

As we all know, `sed` is greatly efficient to find and replace string, for example find 'a' 
and replace it to 'b': `sed 's/a/b/g'`.

Is it possible to do this with other command or shell script instead of `sed`?

This is for a cropped linux systems for TV that does not have the `sed` command. So I have to use other commands or scripts instead of `sed 's/a/b/g'. –`

Comment: Actually, that is just regular expression based substitution. Any tool or language capable to handle such thing will be able to do the same, but with various syntax: `$var=~s/a/b/g`, `gsub(/a/,"b",var)`, `var.gsub(/a/,'b')`, `var.replace(/a/g,'b')`, `preg_replace("/a/","b",$var)`, `regsub -all a b $var`. Beside that, many tools and languages can also do plain text string replacement. So your question is somehow broad.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: A cropped linux systems for TV have not sed command. So I has to use other command or script to instead of sed 's/a/b/g'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there are a variety of ways to do this. You can use `awk`, `perl`, or `bash` to do these activities as well. In general though `sed` is probably the most apropos tool for doing these types of tasks.

#### Examples

Say I have this sample data, in a file `data.txt`:

```
foo bar 12,300.50
foo bar 2,300.50
abc xyz 1,22,300.50
```

*awk*

```
$ awk '{gsub("foo", "foofoofoo", $0); print}' data.txt 
foofoofoo bar 12,300.50
foofoofoo bar 2,300.50
abc xyz 1,22,300.50
```

*Perl*

```
$ perl -pe "s/foo/foofoofoo/g" data.txt 
foofoofoo bar 12,300.50
foofoofoo bar 2,300.50
abc xyz 1,22,300.50
```

#### Inline editing

The above examples can directly modify the files too. The Perl example is trivial. Simply add the `-i` switch.

```
$ perl -pie "s/foo/foofoofoo/g" data.txt
```

For `awk` it's a little less direct but just as effective:

```
$ { rm data.txt && awk '{gsub("foo", "foofoofoo", $0); print}' > data.txt; } < data.txt
```

This method creates a sub-shell with the braces '{ ... }` where the file is redirected into it via this:

```
$ { ... } < data.txt
```

Once the file has been redirected into the sub-shell, it's deleted and then `awk` is run against the contents of the file that was read into the sub-shells STDIN. This content is then processed by `awk` and written back out to the same file name that we just deleted, effectively replacing it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and i will try it next workday.But i am not sure if it work because some command maybe not exist in a cropped linux systems of TV,such as 'sed'.So i still want to use command 'find','grep' and so on to solve it.

Comment: @binghenzq - I've added examples that inline edit the file.

Comment: -1 I rarely downvote but in this case the point of the question seemed to be a simpler method rather than other more/equally complex and likely also dependent.  If the question was just about alternatives for a full *nix machine install then I would probably +1 this otherwise good answer.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - I just added those elaborate inline edits b/c the OP asked for them. Also the OP set the requirement of *NOT* using `sed` not I. Sed is the appropriate tool for doing substitutions such as this, and he's obviously asking to better understand the roles of these tools, so showing someone these things though bad, are extremely education in showing them why. Too many times the ppl in the know simply say "don't do it" without explaining why, so I am. But thanks for at least leaving a comment as to why you DV.

Comment: Sure, I thought it was a great answer in all other respects.  yeah I hate -1 with no explanation.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - so should I remove those things?

Comment: I wouldn't but that's up to you.  Also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98577/alternative-to-sed ;)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - I thought that was why you DV'ed it?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - I'm so sorry to bring haress,but some shell command wasn't exist in a cropped linux systems which I have.So I have to do this in another way.

Answer (score 18):

The classic alternative for single letter substitutions is the [`tr`](http://www.ss64.com/bash/tr.html) command which should be available on just about any system:

```
$ echo "foobar" | tr a b   
foobbr
```

`tr` is better than `sed` for this actually since using `sed` (let alone `perl` or `awk`) for single letter substitutions is like using a sledge hammer to kill a fly.

`grep` is not designed for this, it does not modify its input, it only searches through it.

Alternatively, you can use the [substitution capabilities](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) of some shells. Here using `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash` syntax:

```
$ foo="foobar"
$ echo "${foo//a/b}"
foobbr
```

We could give you more specific answers if you explained exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Is there an option to ignore case in `${foo//a/b}`?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I'm afraid not. You'll have to use something more sophisticated like, for example: `echo "$foo" | sed 's/a/b/i` or give a character class: `echo ${foo//[aA]/b}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the POSIX tool `ex`:

```
ex a.txt <<eof
%s/Sunday/Monday/g
xit
eof
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Comment: great thanks. just to add, -c flag is to execute the command when editing begins (since ex is an editor) and -s flag is either script mode disabling feedback or as some like to say slient-mode. ref for more info: http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/ex.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with a file rather than a stream, you could use the standard text editor, `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' ',s/a/b/g' w q | ed file.txt
```

This should be available on any *nix. The comma in `',s/a/b/g'` tells `ed` to work on *every* line (you can also use `%`, which will be more familiar if you're used to vim), and the rest of it is a standard search and replace. `w` tells it to write (save) the file, `q` tells it to exit.

Note that, unlike sed's `-i` option (and similar options in other tools), this actually does edit the file in-place rather than cheating with temporary files.

I don't think it's possible to get this working with streams, but then I don't really know much about `ed` and I wouldn't be surprised if it actually does have that capability (the unix philosophy being what it is).

Answer (score 2):

Using the ancestor [ed](/questions/tagged/ed) command (in which `-s` means quiet (silent) and the comma before the commands means execute on all lines):

Just printing on *STDOUT*:

```
ed -s file <<!
,s/a/b/g
,p
q
!
```

replacing in-place:

```
ed -s file <<!
,s/a/b/g
w
q
!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux OS eg Ubuntu Desktop like me, you will have `python` installed.

With python, we can do text replacing as below

```bsh
result=$(python << EOT
s = '$your_string_in_shell_script'
r = s.replace('text to replace', 'replaced by this text')
print(r)
EOT)

echo $result
```